# Version problem in php

Tags: php

I upgraded my system from Windows xp to windows 7. When i was in win xp i used the wamp server with php version 5.0 now i installed the wamp server with the version 5.3. But now it's making problem. The old projects are not running. Even-though they are created in php version 5. How i can solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "The old projects are not running"? What happens? Also see http://php.net/migration53

Comment: Please include the specific problem / bug.

Comment: this question could be of help: http://superuser.com/questions/111283/mysql-doesnt-talk-to-php-anymore-easyphp

Comment: The projects are running properly with the version 5.0 but it's not running with 5.3!!

Comment: Error reporting is probably not turned on.

Comment: Mayilarun: that is not a specific problem. What does "not running " mean? What isn't working that used to work before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New versions of WAMP use apache 2.2.x and lovest php version supported for that is 5.2. That beeing said you can downgrade your php version of wamp installation by downloading a php addon http://www.wampserver.com/en/addons_php.php from here. Or you can ultimately downgrade WAMP apache installation from 2.2 to 2.0 http://www.wampserver.com/en/addons_apache.php . If your project don't work with 5.2 or 5.3 you need to debug and update your code with the latest changes in php http://php.net/migration53

Comment: yeah, let's work on old php version just because we are to lazy to fix compatibility errors.

Comment: @OZ_ There was no question to fix any code related stuff, but rather projects not running. So i help with what i can.

Answer (score 1):

There are some (but not many) backward-incompatible changes between PHP 5.0 and 5.3. But they're fairly obscure and not generally going to cause major issues. You can find the full details here: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php

However my guess is that it's more likely that you've installed the new version missing one or more extensions which your code is relying on.

For example, if you are using the pdo_xx() functions, you would need the PDO extension. Most PHP programs will use functionality from several extensions, and not all of them may be included in the default installation, so you need to ensure you have installed with all the ones you need.

The other possibility is that there's an issue with the installation (either PHP itself or the web server, etc) that is preventing PHP from running at all.

But this is all really a guess, because you haven't actually told us anything about what exactly the problem is. You need to look and see in what way it's failing. If you're not getting error messages in the browser, check the server error logs. This is the quickest way to diagnose the problem. It should give you some good clues (if it doesn't help you understand what's happening, paste the relevant log entries here, because they'll definitely make sense to someone)